# PHP - Handle upload traffic

Tags: php, file-upload, traffic

I'm building a desktop app to let people upload images through PHP. 
If a lot of users want to upload images at the same time I'm worried if one PHP file will handle it.

Should I create multiple instances like *upload-gate-1.php*, *upload-gate-2.php* and so on to deploy the traffic?

Thanks,
Uli

Comment: No at all. Have you heared about threading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webserver will take care of this for you: It will create as many ACTIVE instances of upload-gate.php as necessary, each of them independent of the others.

Comment: Thank you. Then I'm not worried anymore.